# Scroll automatically to the right side of a datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there any way, in R Shiny, to set the scroll bar from a datatable automatically to the right side when rendered (i.e. to the last column), instead of the left side as it is set by default ?

Base example :

```
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("results", width = 300)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$results <- DT::renderDataTable(
      mtcars,
      options = list(scrollX = TRUE, bPaginate = F)
    )
  }
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$div(id = "parent",
      DT::dataTableOutput("results", width = 300)
    ),
    tags$style("
               #parent {direction: rtl; max-height: 80vh; overflow: auto; margin: 0 auto} 
               #results {direction: ltr; float: left}")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$results <- DT::renderDataTable(
      mtcars,
      options = list(scrollX = TRUE, bPaginate = F)
    )
  }
))
```

---

### EDIT

Here is what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- "
$('div.dataTables_scrollBody').animate({scrollLeft: '+=500'}, 1000);
"

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DTOutput("results", width = 300)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$results <- renderDT(
      datatable(
        mtcars, 
        callback = JS(callback),
        options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
      )
    )
  }
))
```

1000 is 1000ms, this is the duration of the animation. I don't understand why +=300 is not enough.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as expected, for my part.

Comment: Don't you mean the left side? The right side is the default.

Comment: Yep, it is scrolled to the left side, as it would be by default; results from the above code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8GVv.png

Comment: ? The default is the right side, not the left side. There's nothing to do if you want the scrollbar at the right side.

Comment: I think there has been a misunderstanding. I'm looking to set the X scroll bar to the right side. I'm not talking about the Y scroll bar, which is indeed set to the right side by default.

Comment: But this scroll bar is horizontal. What does it mean to set it at the right?

Comment: Ah ok I understand now. Let me think about it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg2pO.png thank you for your help

Comment: @Kamaloka See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in the ui: `tags$style('#results {direction: rtl;}')`

```
library(shiny)
runApp(shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        DT::dataTableOutput("results", width = 300),
        tags$style('#results {direction: rtl;}')
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$results <- DT::renderDataTable(
            mtcars,
            options = list(scrollX = TRUE, bPaginate = F)
        )
    }
))
```

Comment: adding ```tags$style('#results {direction: rtl;}')``` seems to reverse the whole table, while I'd like to keep the table with the same shape

Comment: Good point, I missed that. If you're not using the rownames column then the "hacky" way would be to just reverse the columns `mtcars[,order(ncol(mtcars):1)]` but hopefully someone more experienced in CSS can assist.